# STM32 - ADC Vref

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, stm32

I want to measure voltage using an ADC. A servo is powered by a 6V battery and controlled by PWM, so it requires the STM32's and battery grounds to be connected.

This causes the wrong voltage to be read (STM is powered by 5 V). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It depends how they are connected now. To know that, show the schematics.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the problem is.  If you add a diagram showing exactly how everything is connected, we may be able to help.

Comment: Are you sure, your STM32 is powered by 5V? - as Justme stated, please add a schmematic to see, what you are doing.

Comment: STM32 is powered by 5V - then your STM is dead